# authorisation with Spring Security Grails plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

### Background

I'm using the Spring Security Grails plugin. Because my User and Role classes are not GORM objects, I  I've replaced the `UserDetailsService` provided by the plugin with my own implementation:

```
class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    static transactional = false
    private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this)

    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager

    @Autowired
    private RoleManager roleManager

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userManager.getUserByEmail(username)
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserAdapter(user, roleManager)

        log.debug "user '$username' has roles: ${userDetails.authorities?.authority}"
        userDetails       
    }
}
```

### Problem

When I login, I see the following message is logged from `CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername()`

> user 'a5511120@nepwk.com' has roles: [USER]

So it seems that the user has been assigned the USER role. However, when I then try and access an action of this controller:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR'])
class MyProfileController {
    def someAction = { // impl omitted }
}
```

I get bounced to the access denied page. I'm pretty sure that the user is logged in, because the access denied page contains markup such as

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
  protected content
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

and the protected content is displayed. So it seems that somehow the USER role is not associated with the current user, when the controller authorisation is performed. The log message suggests that the `UserDetailsService` is OK.

Comment: Is USER in the println the same as ROLE_USER?

Comment: `getCurrentUser()` is a utility method for users, but it's not used by the plugin or Spring Security, so it's not related to this issue. Try setting the 'org.springframework.security' category to debug in your Log4j config - Spring Security is good about dumping verbose info about auth failures.

Comment: Ah, just saw Tim's question - that's probably it. Roles have to start with 'ROLE_' otherwise the `RoleVoter` ignores them.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith @tim_yates Are you saying that `GrantedAuthority.authority` should return a String that begins with 'ROLE_'?

Comment: Yes, always - roles need a prefix to differentiate them from non-role tokens like IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY and it's currently not configurable to anything other than "ROLE_". You can convert them to more presentable strings in your UI of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot Burt (and tim). If you want to convert your comments above into an answer I'll upvote/accept it once I've confirmed it works.

Comment: Tim's the one with the answer :) I just clarified.

Comment: you'll have to sort out ownership of this answer yourselves :) if one of you wants to post an answer under your own name, I'll delete mine and accept yours instead - thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The solution is to make sure that the role names in the domain class/database begin with "ROLE_", as per the annotation parameters.

### Acknowledgements

All credit for this answer goes to @BurtBeckwith and @tim_yates, who provided the solution in comments. I'm converting their comments to an answer, as future readers may easily miss their comments.